# Cannot read property 'then' of undefined with nested function calls

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

The code below is contrived.  I'm simplified things as best I could to ask the question.

I have a simple angular service that makes an API call and returns results:

```
doWork = function(reqId) {
  return $http.get('/api/dowork/' + reqId).then(function(response) {
    return response.data;
  }).catch(function(response) {
    return $q.reject(response.data);
  });
}

mediumRequest = function() {
  var req = 'medium';//normally do something hard to derive this value
  return this.doWork(req);
}
```

In my controller, I can call the doWork function on the service and get back a good response like this:

```
myService.doWork('simple').then(function(response){
    //do something great with response
});
```

However, if I need to call an intermediate method to preprocess the request, I get "Cannot read property 'then' of undefined":

```
myService.mediumRequest().then(function(response){
    //do something great with response
});
```

Why doesn't the function mediumRequest return the promise that doWork returned to it?

Comment: How about `return this.doWork(req)` ??

Comment: Can you please produce a minimum reproducible example which doesn't require API calls?

Comment: I edited my sample code to include the "this.doWork(req)" as this is how my actual service is coded.  @LeonardoChaia   This code fails.

Comment: check your error log - I suspect that `this.doWork` doesn't actually exist (i.e you've got the wrong `this`) and there's an uncaught exception

Answer (score 1):

Try this code , you did wrong in your service

```
 var app = angular.module("myApp", [])
 .service('myService',function($http,$q){
    this.doWork = function(reqId) {
     return $http.get('/api/dowork/'+ reqId).then(function(response) {
      return response.data;
    }).catch(function(response) {
      return $q.reject(response.data);
    });
  };

  this.mediumRequest = function() {
    var req = 'medium';//normally do something hard to derive this value
    return this.doWork(req);
  };
})

 app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope,$compile,myService) {
   myService.doWork('simple').then(function(response){
     console.log('b',response)
   });
   myService.mediumRequest().then(function(response){
    console.log('a',response)
  });
})
```

It will work

Answer (score 0):

As with most things, the problem was a coding error in my actual service code.  The code I've presented in this question would work as expected.  I appreciate the couple of folks who offered suggestions of ways to identify the issue.  Here was my issue:

My actual "intermediate" function had this structure:

```
mediumRequest = function(options) {
  //process first option meeting criteria
  options.forEach(function (item) {
      if(item.meetsCriteria)
      {
        var req = item.code;
        return this.doWork(req);
      }
  });
}
```

As you can see, the return is actually just exiting the forEach and never actually being returned from the mediumRequest function.  Hence the error.

Comment: so as I surmised, your `this` wasn't correct, either.